# how to split an arraylist of String whenever a space is encountered in java?

Tags: java, arraylist, split

I have an input like this in an `ArrayList<String>`:

```
cat eats mouse

mouse eats cheese
cheese is tasty
```

(blank lines should be ignored since I will be reading this input from a file)

and I want to convert it into a 2-d array of String which will have dimensions `[no. of elements in ArrayList][3]`.

The no. 3 is fixed i.e. each sentence will have 3 words.
like this:

```
"cat"    "eats" "mouse"
"mouse"  "eats" "cheese"
"cheese" "is"   "tasty"
```

here's what I have tried:

```
    public static int processData(ArrayList<String> array)
    {
        String str[]=new String[array.size()];
        array.toArray(str);

        String str1[][]=new String[str.length][5];
        for(int i=0;i<str.length;i++)
        {
                str1[i][]=str.split("\\s+");    //i want to do something like this, but this is showing errors.

        }

        return 0; //this is temporary, I will be modifying it
    }
```

Tell me if I am not clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are close. In Java, you can't put new elements at the end of an array by using empty brackets `[]`. The following code does the thing. Note that number of elements in the second array is limited by 5. So, after the first 5 words, the rest of the line will be ignored. If the line is shorter, there will be `null`s in the end of the array.

```
public static int processData(ArrayList<String> array) {
    String[] str = new String[array.size()];
    array.toArray(str);

    String[][] str1 = new String[str.length][3];

    for(int i=0; i < str.length; i++) {
        String[] parts = str[i].split("\\s+");

        for(int j = 0; j < parts.length || j < 3; j++) {
            str1[i][j] = parts[j];
        }
    }

    // do something next
}
```

Comment: I don't know why but str.split() is showing errors: `Cannot invoke split(String) on the array type String[]`

Comment: Also, a better practice is to declare arrays as `String[] str`, not `String str[]`.

Comment: Yeah I will do that.. but how to i remove that error/

Comment: Why the 5? Why copying the strings with a loop instead of just assigning the reference from split()?

Comment: i did that : `String parts[] = str[i].split("\\s+");`  Thanks for the help!

Comment: I've changed the 5 to 3. Also, you can add a parameter to the split function to ensure there will be no more than three elements in the array, but that would not affect the behavior of this solution.

Comment: Using 5 as the second dimension when you need just 3 is a only waste of memory. Then you can simplify the logic and avoid the second for. Never ever write code that is more complicated than it should be. Think about maintenance.

Answer (score 2):

A shorter, and slightelly more efficient version:

```
static int processData(ArrayList<String> array)
{
    String str[][] = new String[array.size()][3];
    for(int i = 0; i < str.length; ++i) {
        str[i] = array.get(i).split("\\s+");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

There is no reasion for the first array called *str* in your code, since you cann access the Strings directly from the ArrayList.

Also you can don't have to copy the Strings, you can just put the arrays of Strings into the array of arrays, like in my code

Plus, if you have a fixed size of 3, and don't need to add any more to the arrays, why do you allocate space for 5 strings?

Comment: Unless you don't need the one-dimensional `str` array, this may be better. I started from the newbie's code while giving the answer to show what necessary changes must be made

Comment: I understand what you did, and as I said, I think your answer is correct, I just wanted to point out, that there is a way to do it a little bit more efficient, since @Newbie seems to be new and may have done this, because he didn't know the `get()` function

Comment: Thanks i will try this.. +1 for helping

Comment: I needed actually 5 elements but for the sake of simplicity i mentioned 3 here so that I can show the input and desired output in a shorter way..

Answer (score 0):

Change your for loop to:

```
String str1[][] = new String[str.length][3];
for(int i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    str1[i] = str[i].split("\\s+");    
}
```

You don't need to have 5 elements if you know that you have only 3 words, do not waste your resources.

`str` is a `String[]`, `str[i]` is a `String`, `str[i].split()` is a `String[]` and so is `str1[i]`. The types match.

Also, this way the code is clearer and easier to understand. I agree with **Ongy** to remove `str` if you do not need it, but I can't tell now because you said you are going to change this method later (at least the return value)

**Bonus**: Btw, the names `array`, `str`, `str1` are not the best choice for that piece of code, it is really easy to be confused what is what. Try finding better name such as `lines`, `linesArray`, `words` or something like that

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned "arraylist" in Subject:

```
try{
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("filename"));
    Arraylist<String[]> l = new ArrayList<String[]>();
    String line;
    while((line = br.readline) != null)
      l.add(line.split("\\s+");

    br.close();
}catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
```

Comment: i have already read the file contents in the main function in the arraylist.. I am passing it to this function